# Domain of an interpolated polynomial function

Tags: analysis, functions, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I was just wondering what defined the domain of a Lagrange interpolating polynomial. Is it the domain of the function being interpolated? Always the reals? I am asking this as I have constructed a function using polynomial interpolation and I want to know if I can just give it a complex valued input. Is that rigourous?

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from substituting complex values into the Lagrange interpolating polynomial.